# read unknown number of lines and calculate summation of each line in f#

Tags: f#

Say I have n (4 in this case) inputs given

```
5 2
3 2
1 8
9 0
```

How do I read all inputs and store summation of each line in a list/array?

Comment: How are the inputs coming to your program? From a file, read from command line, fed as arguments to a function...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need a function to parse and sum one line:

```
open System

let parseAndSumLine (s: string) =
    let numbers = s.Split ' '
    Int32.Parse numbers.[0] + Int32.Parse numbers.[1]
```

With this you can read all lines from a file using `File.ReadAllLines` and map the result through `parseAndSumLine`:

```
open System.IO

let sums =
    File.ReadAllLines "path/to/file"
    |> Array.map parseAndSumLine
```